# AngularJS $resource Headers POST

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I would like to know how to pass headers to AngularJS $resource method

Here is the factory method

```
.factory('DataRepository', function ($resource) {
            return $resource(serviceUrlPrefix + '/api/v1/AppList/:id', { id: '@id' }, { 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false }, 'update': { method: 'PUT', AppList: '@req', headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XmlHttpRequest' } } });
        });
```

Here is the call to the dataRepository

```
dataRepository.update({ id: req[uniqueIDColumn] }, req, function (data) {                
        },
         function (error) {
         });
```

This code works fine. But i have few queries

**Question 1:**
Rather than specifying the headers in the factory method , how can i specify it in the call to the factory method? I tried few methods but it didnt work out.

**Question 2:**
I specified the header in the update method in the factory. When i perform "Save" using that factory, that header has been taken by default. But i have specified it explicitly for PUT method. Right? Why and how?

**Question 3:**
If i would like to specify the header for the particular factory in common for all Http methods, what is the way to do it?

**Question 4:**
What is the nomenclature for passing the parameters and the significance of "@" symbol before parameter and also in the below part, AppList is the parameter name used in the WebAPI, is it mandatory that it should match the parameter name in the WebAPI method, if its not matching, its not working:(

```
AppList: '@req'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid we don't use $resource, but it does depend on $http. We configure the header with the below. Not sure about the rest of your questions.

I will say that we also do not use $http directly. We created our own "requestHelper" service that we inject everywhere. That allows us to inject things before making calls to $http as well as catch the response before passing the result on to the real caller. Helps with common error handling.

Configure headers for $http:

```js
module.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I m yet to test on this and i assume setting the default header in the above mentioned approach would suit for $resource as well.. Please correct me if i m wrong.